# Show the log trace of logslf4J and tomcat in a textArea

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, log4j, tomcat7

I'm using Java EE and I want to show the log trace of logslf4J and Tomcat in a textArea.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how this open source project makes the Tomcat logs accessible.

http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/